# Issues installing Komorebi on Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB

Tags: dependencies, raspberrypi

I know little about Linux but I do want to learn. I'm trying to install Komorebi on this thing but I hit multiple issues. This is a 64-bit version of Ubuntu and I've tried a full OS reinstall to no avail. Nothing special about the install, I flashed the card using the Pi Imager with the 64-bit version from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi).

So I download Komorebi 2.1 from this [github link](https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi/releases) then I right-clicked it in my downloads folder and hit "Open with Software Install" which opens up and has me hit "install" on that page and enter the password. After that, it tries to run then I get a pop-up saying "Unable to install Komorebi: The following packages have unmet dependencies:" and it doesn't tell me which dependencies I need.

The below might not be relevant, but here's what I tried:

To resolve this, I made sure to run "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade". Then I tried again, no luck. I have tried running the .deb package again, no luck. I installed aptitude and tried with that, but aptitude can't find the file for Komorebi whether I try the address to the package or if I drag and drop it. Tried to clean up packages with "sudo apt-get install -f" and "sudo dpkg --configure -a" but all I get is "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded."

Essentially what I know so far is that these packages (like Komorebi) have prerequisites (these dependencies) that need to be installed before I can use the package. I have a [list of the dependencies for Komorebi 2.0](https://ostechnix.com/set-animated-video-wallpapers-linux-desktop/) (although 2.1 is the latest version) but where do they come from? How do I get them?

Also the purpose of this is to get a pc monitoring screen inside my pc case and learn some Linux in the process. I want Komorebi because I want to display gifs and stuff while the screen idles. If someone has a better idea on doing this I'm happy to take suggestions!

Comment: Update, I tried to install one of the dependencies using these directions (https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libgtop2-dev) and got 2 errors
First one says that it has no release file
Second one says the repository can't be downloaded securely

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look the software is built for AMD64 but the pi uses ARM64 and is incompatible.